# How to insert a string in another string in C

Tags: c, string

I need to insert a string in another string at a specific place. Here's a simple example:

```
char *a = "Dany S.";
char *b = "My name is  *a , I come from ...  ";
```

So, in string `b` in place of `*a` I expect to have `Dany S.`

How to do that ?

Comment: String literals can **not** be modified. Copy the content to array. Search for the string to be replaced. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Ever heard of the C standard library?

Comment: I should really make you look through the standard library, it would do you good to have an idea what's in there, but I'll be nice and say [`snprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Comment: *a is inside quote marks so it's just two characters; it does not refer to the variable. Moreover *a is the same as a[0] so it's only one character; just a 'D'

Comment: [Inserting strings into another string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46958109/995714)

Answer (score 11):

The best/easiest way would be to use standard C conventions:

```
char *a = "Dany S.";
char *b = "My name is %s, I come from...";

char *c = malloc(strlen(a) + strlen(b));

sprintf( c, b, a );
```

Then `c` contains your new string. When you're done with `c`, you will need to free the memory:

```
free( c );
```

If you want to use `c` in an output that terminates the line, then you can declare `b` as:

```
char *b = "My name is %s, I come from...\n";
```

Comment: What about the end of line character?

Comment: Sizeof of the char* doesn't return the size of the string. Use strlen for that.

Comment: @AdamGalarneau do you mean end of line or end of string? End of line wasn't indicated by the OP as a need. End of string is taken care of implicitly. I caught my `sizeof` problem just before you made your comment. :)

Comment: .... can't you assume he's gonna need it? or at least indicate that he may need it in the answer instead of just ignoring it? If you do, you'll get a +1 from me. =D

Comment: @AdamGalarneau why would I assume he needs an end of line? How do you know he isn't going to use the string in some other context? To assume end of line would be quite specific to a particular application that he didn't indicate. If he wanted an end of line, he would/should include it in `b`.

Comment: You still need the `+1` for the null terminator.

Comment: @Kevin, the two string lengths actually give the +1 and a little more due to the length of `%s`.

Comment: I'm not saying he really needs it, I just feel the answer isn't complete without at least talking about it. This guy don't know how to concatenate strings.. super basic stuff. So make sure to cover the basic stuff in your answer and you'll be the best.

Comment: @Macmade, if you look at the length of the original strings, you'll find that there's enough room. Remember that `a` is replacing a `%s` in the original string. So I get the +1 for free. :)

Comment: +1 for ya cause you're a gentlemen.

Comment: @mbratch Yep, that's why I deleted my previous comment... +1 anyway...

Comment: Thanks, works as I expected ;)

Comment: IMHO it is useful to point out that after that `malloc` the OP is in charge to `free` that memory chunk pointed by `c`, otherwise he may leak memory (he seems to be a newbie).

Comment: I'll upvote if you remove the cast.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths done. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use printf i.e.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *a = "Dany S.";
char *b = "My name is  %s , I come from ...  ";

printf(b, a);
```

Comment: Isn't it sprintf instead?

Comment: There is the whole family, printf outputs to stdout, fprintf(file, to a file, sprintf to a string then there are the v.. versions without knowing more about what is required ...

Comment: The question is not how to print something on screen but to " insert a string in another string".