# Inserting strings into another string in C

Tags: c, string, malloc, ansi-c

I'm implementing a function which, given a string, a character and another string (since now we can call it the "substring"); puts the substring everywhere the character is in the string.
To explain me better, given these parameters this is what the function should return (pseudocode):

```
func ("aeiou", 'i', "hello")  ->  aehelloou
```

I'm using some functions from `string.h` lib. I have tested it with pretty good result:

```
char *somestring= "this$ is a tes$t wawawa$wa";
printf("%s", strcinsert(somestring, '$', "WHAT?!") );

Outputs:    thisWHAT?! is a tesWHAT?!t wawawaWHAT?!wa
```

so for now everything is allright. The problem is when I try to do the same with, for example this string:

```
char *somestring= "this \"is a test\" wawawawa";
printf("%s", strcinsert(somestring, '"', "\\\"") );
```

since I want to change every `"` for a `\"` . When I do this, the PC collapses. I don't know why but it stops working and then shutdown. I've head some about the bad behavior of some functions of the `string.h` lib but I couldn't find any information about this, I really thank any help.

My code:

```
#define salloc(size) (str)malloc(size+1) //i'm lazy
typedef char* str;

str strcinsert (str string, char flag, str substring)
{
    int nflag= 0; //this is the number of times the character appears
    for (int i= 0; i<strlen(string); i++)
        if (string[i]==flag)
            nflag++;
    str new=string;
    int pos;
    while (strchr(string, flag)) //since when its not found returns NULL
    {
        new= salloc(strlen(string)+nflag*strlen(substring)-nflag);
        pos= strlen(string)-strlen(strchr(string, flag));
        strncpy(new, string, pos);
        strcat(new, substring);
        strcat(new, string+pos+1);
        string= new;      
    }
    return new;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `typedef char* str;` <- nasty

Comment: That macro - also nasty.

Comment: `strchr(string, flag)` is looking over the whole string for `flag`.  Search needs to be limited to the portion of the string not yet examined/updated.

Comment: :( i come from python come on

Comment: New is not a good choice of variable name

Comment: This is overly complex as well ... a single allocation should do.

Comment: Btw, using `new` as an identifier definitely makes this code invalid for C++, so casting the result of `malloc()` is at best redundant.

Comment: 'new= salloc(strlen(string)+nflag*strlen(substring)-nflag);' - NUL terminator space?

Comment: @MartinJames it's hidden in the macro. Yes, nasty macro.

Comment: damn @chux its true

Comment: What do you mean by “the PC collapses”? Do you mean everything completely freezes until you need to force the computer off, or does the one program freeze up until you kill it? Either way I don’t know how you’d get that reaction; my guess is that there’s a bug relating to the inserted string containing the replaced character, but I wouldn’t expect it to manifest like that given your code. EDIT: Oh, I see. You don’t use `nflag` the way I’d expect.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Dreck - so it is.  Isa hate 'dem macros to pieces.

Comment: You should also know that, unlike in Python, `strlen` is not practically free. You should cache the result, instead of calling it over and over.

Comment: [check this](https://ideone.com/t01loA) for an (IMHO) sane implementation. Note the "const correctness" as well as the need to free what you get from `malloc()`.

Comment: `strncpy` doesn't always NUL terminate the string so you'll be hitting undefined behaviour

Comment: Updated my example from the comment above, it now scans the input string "*only*" *twice* (It was three times before due to an unneeded `strlen()`). Doing it in a single pass would only be possible by allocating an upper bound of memory first, probably not a good idea.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Interesting  to review your [code](https://ideone.com/t01loA) and [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46958586/2410359) similarities. Review from the [MAS](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mutual_admiration_society): Nice work.

Comment: @chux I see, the basic ideas are exactly the same ;) (and you didn't introduce an unnecessary `strlen()` first ....)

Comment: @FelixPalmen hmm.  maybe with recursion?  The last call could allocate the accumulated space, and the returns could copy in the stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advices:

- refrain from `typedef char* str;`. The `char *` type is common in C and masking it will just make your code harder to be reviewed
- refrain from `#define salloc(size) (str)malloc(size+1)` for the exact same reason. In addition **don't cast `malloc` in C**
- each time you write a `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`) there should be a corresponding `free`: C has no garbage collection
- dynamic allocation is expensive, use it only when needed. Said differently a `malloc` inside a loop should be looked at twice (especially if there is no corresponding `free`)
- always test allocation function (unrelated: and io) a malloc will simply return NULL when you exhaust memory. A nice error message is then easier to understand than a crash
- learn to use a debugger: if you had executed your code under a debugger the error would have been evident

Next the cause: if the replacement string contains the original one, you fall again on it and run in an endless loop

A possible workaround: allocate the result string *before* the loop and advance both in the original one and the result. It will save you from unnecessary allocations and de-allocations, and will be immune to the original char being present in the replacement string.

Possible code:

```
// the result is an allocated string that must be freed by caller
str strcinsert(str string, char flag, str substring)
{
    int nflag = 0; //this is the number of times the character appears
    for (int i = 0; i<strlen(string); i++)
        if (string[i] == flag)
            nflag++;
    str new_ = string;
    int pos;
    new_ = salloc(strlen(string) + nflag*strlen(substring) - nflag);
    // should test new_ != NULL
    char * cur = new_;
    char *old = string;
    while (NULL != (string = strchr(string, flag))) //since when its not found returns NULL
    {
        pos = string - old;
        strncpy(cur, old, pos);
        cur[pos] = '\0';             // strncpy does not null terminate the dest. string
        strcat(cur, substring);
        strcat(cur, string + 1);
        cur += strlen(substring) + pos; // advance the result
        old = ++string;                 // and the input string
    }
    return new_;
}
```

Note: I have not reverted the `str` and `salloc` but you really should do.

Comment: `strlen(string)` is a loop is [computational expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958109/inserting-strings-into-another-string-in-c?noredirect=1#comment80864007_46958109) with compilers that do not understand/optimize this call.  Yet this code does retain OP's style

Comment: A corner problem with `strchr(string, flag)` is when `flag == 0`.  The `while` loop will iterate adn the null character is found and then with `old = ++string;`, the next `strchr(string, ...` will be UB.

Answer (score 1):

In your second loop, you always look for the first `flag` character in the string. In this case, that’ll be the one you just inserted from `substring`. The `strchr` function will always find that quote and never return `NULL`, so your loop will never terminate and just keep allocating memory (and not enough of it, since your string grows arbitrarily large).

Speaking of allocating memory, you need to be more careful with that. Unlike in Python, C doesn’t automatically notice when you’re no longer using memory; anything you `malloc` *must* be `free`d. You also allocate far more memory than you need: even in your working `"this$ is a tes$t wawawa$wa"` example, you allocate enough space for the full string on *each iteration* of the loop, and never `free` any of it. You should just run the allocation once, before the second loop.

This isn’t *as* important as the above stuff, but you should also pay attention to performance. Each call to `strcat` and `strlen` iterates over the entire string, meaning you look at it far more often than you need. You should instead save the result of `strlen`, and copy the new string directly to where you know the NUL terminator is. The same goes for `strchr`; you already replaced the beginning of the string and don’t want to waste time looking at it again, apart from the part where that’s causing your current bug.

In comparison to these issues, the style issues mentioned in the comments with your typedef and macro are relatively minor, but they are still worth mentioning. A `char*` in C is different from a `str` in Python; trying to `typedef` it to the same name just makes it more likely you’ll try to treat them as the same and run into these issues.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know why but it stops working

`strchr(string, flag)` is looking over the whole string for flag. Search needs to be limited to the portion of the string not yet examined/updated.  By re-searching the partially replaces string, code is finding the `flag` over and over.

---

The whole string management approach needs re-work.  As OP reported a Python background, I've posted a very C approach as mimicking Python is not a good approach here.  C is different especially in the management of memory.

---

Untested code

```
// Look for needles in a haystack and replace them
// Note that replacement may be "" and result in a shorter string than haystack
char *strcinsert_alloc(const char *haystack, char needle, const char *replacment) {
  size_t n = 0;
  const char *s = haystack;
  while (*s) {
    if (*s == needle) n++;  // Find needle count
    s++;
  }
  size_t replacemnet_len = strlen(replacment);
  //                        string length  - needles + replacements      + \0
  size_t new_size = (size_t)(s - haystack) - n*1     + n*replacemnet_len + 1;
  char *dest = malloc(new_size);
  if (dest) {
    char *d = dest;
    s = haystack;
    while (*s) {
      if (*s == needle) {
        memcpy(d, s, replacemnet_len);
        d += replacemnet_len;
      } else {
        *d = *s;
        d++;
      }
      s++;
    }
    *d = '\0';
  }
  return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your program, you are facing problem for input -

```
char *somestring= "this \"is a test\" wawawawa";
```

as you want to replace `"` for a `\"`.

The first problem is whenever you replace `"` for a `\"` in `string`, in next iteration `strchr(string, flag)` will find the last inserted `"` of `\"`. So, in subsequent interations your string will form like this -

```
this \"is a test" wawawawa
this \\"is a test" wawawawa
this \\\"is a test" wawawawa
```

So, for input string `"this \"is a test\" wawawawa"` your while loop will run for infinite times as every time `strchr(string, flag)` finds the last inserted `"` of `\"`.

The second problem is the memory allocation you are doing in your `while` loop in every iteration. There is no `free()` for the allocated memory to `new`. So when `while` loop run infinitely, it will eat up all the memory which will lead to - `the PC collapses`.

To resolve this, in every iteration, you should search for `flag` only in the string starting from a character after the last inserted `substring` to the end of the string. Also, make sure to `free()` the dynamically allocated memory.